# Sum of 'inverse' Normal (1/X) random variables. Equivalent resistance calculation

Tags: asymptotics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Consider the case of $N$ resistances $R$ connected [in parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits). The equivalent resistance of such a circuit is calculated as follows

$$ \frac{1}{R_{eq}} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{R} + ..... + \frac{1}{R}}_{\text{N times}} \quad\quad  (1)$$

In the case (here) of equivalent resistances, this trivially simplifies to

$$ R_{eq} = \frac{R}{N} \quad \quad  (2) $$

Edit following the comments: This reasoning holds only for the resistance being an algebraic variable. Now, I would like to perform the same calculation but by replacing $R$ by $\bar{R}$, where $\bar{R}$ is now a random variable following the law $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and obviously equation (2) doesn't hold in general anymore for random variables.

So, consider now that the resistance is a normally distributed random variable 
$$ \bar{R} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) $$

Given this, I would like to calculate the (asymptotic) distribution of $\bar{R}_{eq}$. Not being an expert in statistics, I cannot say anything about the law behavior of the sum in (1). I know that the [reciprocal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#reciprocal_normal_distribution) distribution of a normal variable is [bimodal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution), but cannot take it from there. Apparently I could not even apply the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) on sum (1) since the bimodal distribution doesn't have a first nor a second moment.

From a statistical analysis, it seems that 
$$ \bar{R}_{eq} \overset{N}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu}{N},\frac{\sigma^2}{N^2}\right) $$

which indicates that equation (2) holds even as a law behavior. Can you see any way of deriving this last relationship analytically ?

Comment: You have not defined what $\bar{R}$ is, and/or how it differs from $R$.

Comment: Also, your equation (2) is not correct (other than for $n=1$). You are confusing algebra ... with the algebra of random variables (which is not the same thing). For example, the sum of two iid random variables $X_1$ + $X_2$ is NOT equal to $2 X$. Presumably, you intend to write:  $$\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} +  \dots + \frac{1}{R_n} $$  where $R_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ ??

Comment: Further, I presume that resistance must be positive? As in cannot be negative?  If so, using a Normal distribution is not the right approach ... especially algebraically, even if you assume that $\mu$ is large positive, because the inverting process becomes an unnecessary mess due to the negative part of the domain of support.

Comment: wolfies, 

I have edited the post. I am aware of the difference between algebra... and the algebra of random variables, and it is precisely because of this I need help.
In the first part I explain how an equivalent resistance is calculated for simple scalars. 
Then, I would like to perform the same calculation but with random variables, which I denoted with a bar.

The normal approximation for the distribution $\bar{R}$ is an approximation (we are working with $\mu \simeq 300$ and $\sigma \simeq 5$

Answer (score 1):

**The Question**

Let $(R_1, \dots, R_n)$ denote an IID sample of size $n$, where $R_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and let:

$$Z = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \dots + \frac{1}{R_n}$$

Find the asymptotic distribution of $R_{eq}  = \large\frac{1}{Z}$.

**OP asks**

> From a statistical analysis, it seems that 
>   $$ R_{eq} \overset{n}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu}{n},\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}\right) $$
>
> ... Can you see any way of deriving this last relationship analytically ?

**Answer:**
No, because the relationship is wrong, and does not hold.

*Theoretically*, even if one could apply the Central Limit Theorem, it would be the pdf of $Z$ that would be asymptotically Normal ... not the pdf of $1/Z$.

To illustrate that it does not work, here is a one-line Monte Carlo simulation of $Z$ (in *Mathematica*), as a function of $n$, when say $\mu = 300$ and $\sigma = 5$:

```
Zdata[n_] := Plus@@Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[300,5], 10^5]^-1, {n}];
```

The following plot compares the:

- the empirical pdf of $R_{eq}  = \large\frac{1}{Z}$ (squiggly BLUE curve)
- the OP's proposed fit model (dashed red curve)

[image]

Plainly, the fit does not work.

**A better  fit**

Suggested better fit ...

As above, the asymptotic Normal model is not the correct model ... however, if $\mu$ is large relative to $\sigma$, then a Normal fit of form:  $\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu}{n} - blah,\frac{\sigma^2}{n^3}\right)$ appears to perform reasonably well.

For the same example as above, with $n = 100$ (and blah = 0), the fit is:

[image]

For $n  = 800$ (and blah again 0), the fit is worse: 
[image]

Plainly, as $n$ increases, a mean adjustment of some function $blah(\mu, \sigma, n)$ is also required.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose $\mu$ is large compared to $\sigma$ so that negative values have vanishing probability to occur and allow ourselves to perform the taylor expansion described below.

One can approximate the function $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ around $\mu$ by its first order taylor expansion

$$ \frac{1}{\bar{R}} \simeq \frac{1}{\mu} - \frac{1}{\mu^2}\left(\bar{R}-\mu\right)  \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{\mu},\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^4} \right)$$

Therefore, $\frac{1}{\bar{R}_{eq}}$ follows approximately

$$ \frac{1}{\bar{R}_{eq}} := \frac{1}{\bar{R}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\bar{R}} \underbrace{\simeq}_{\text{normal property}} \frac{N}{\bar{R}} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{N}{\mu},\frac{N\sigma^2}{\mu^4}\right)  $$

One can then invert the first relation, assuming $\frac{\sqrt{N}\sigma}{\mu^2} \ll \frac{N}{\mu}$ (so that it still holds):

$$ \frac{1}{\bar{R}_{eq}} \simeq  \frac{N}{\bar{R}} \simeq \frac{N}{\mu} - \frac{N}{\mu^2}(\bar{R}-\mu) \simeq \frac{N}{\mu} - \frac{N^2}{\mu^2}\left(\bar{R}_{eq} - \frac{\mu}{N}\right) $$
Therefore 
$$\bar{R}_{eq} \simeq -\frac{\mu^2}{N^2}\frac{1}{\bar{R}_{eq}} + 2\frac{\mu}{N} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu}{N},\frac{\sigma^2}{N^3}\right)  \quad \quad (\dagger)  $$

**Simulation:**

I have drawn $N$ random variables $\bar{R}_{i}$ from $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$  with $\mu = 300, \sigma = 30$ and proceded to calculate 
$$\bar{R}_{eq} = \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\bar{R}_i}\right)^{-1}$$

50'000 times to get the distribution of $\bar{R}_{eq}$. I binned the results in 100 bins and fitted the distribution with a gaussian. This has been repeated for $N$ ranging from 1 to 200 to get a behavior of the distribution of $\bar{R}_{eq}$ in function of $N$.

[image: For each $N$, the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the gaussian fit are represented, normalized, on a log-log scale. The results fit $(\dagger)$]

For each $N$, the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the gaussian fit are represented, normalized, on a log-log scale. The results fit $(\dagger)$

Comment: The $\frac{\sigma^2}{n^3}$ model is exactly what I have been playing with ... the problem is that a mean adjustment is required as well when $n$ is large, and the fit gets worse for larger $n$, rather than better.

Comment: what do you mean by a 'mean adjustment' ?

Comment: $\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu}{n} - blah,\frac{\sigma^2}{n^3}\right)$

Comment: All this talk of fitting may upset the math purists here ... you might find this question bumped to stats.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: Well that and my approximative formalism to derive the distribution of $\bar{R}_{eq}$ :)